# Copy to clipboard using javascript on the iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad

Is there a way to copy text to the clipboard in iPad using javascript (ie - not using the native selection menu)?

Adding info - 
I don't mind if it requires a user action (ie - click) to trigger it. I know there are a lot of security concerns over this issue. This is just to verify there is no standard solution for this.