# Trigger.io copy link to iPhone clipboard

Tags: javascript, clipboard, trigger.io

is there is any way using javascript or any Trigger.io native method to copy value to the iPhone clipboard ?

I tried a lot of solution for cross browser copy to clipboard but not worked with the  Iphone

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy to clipboard using javascript on the iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338210/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-on-the-ipad)

Comment: Thanks for editing i think may be there is another solution by using Trigger.io native plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've tried JavaScript-only methods, you could make a [Trigger.io native plugin](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_plugins/index.html) which backs onto [UIPasteboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks james ,i found that this is the only solution available now may be in the feature trigger.io provide api allow us to do that without using native plugin